# find out location of phone based on received sms

Tags: java, mobile, sms, location

I am creating a java application to receive messages on pc using `jsms` API. Whenever a user sends a particular message to a no, it receives it and adds to the database, the phone number and the area/ region where it belongs.

The region can either be the area where the phone number is registered, or it can also be the current location of the device. Either of these information will help me.

I would be really glad if any one could any one guide me on how to proceed with finding out the region using java code.

Note: I'm not looking for the country. I'm looking for the state/ region. Preferable Indian states.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/). It basically defines the region based on the number.

There is a JavaScript try page [here](http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo.html) you could perform some tests.

Comment: thanks for the link. This gives the country. I'm looking for something that can give the state, preferably Indian states.